# Carregar Spinner vazio

Tags: java, android

Ao gerar um `Spinner`, ele trás o primeiro valor do `ArrayList` gerado já selecionado.

**Como faço para trazê-lo "vazio" ?**

A melhor opção seria populá-lo com uma função `onClick` ao invés de fazer isso no `onCreate`, por exemplo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um campo vazio antes de popular com o array, este mesmo index sendo 0 você pode usar também como validação caso o usuário não tenha selecionado nenhuma opção.

Exemplo:

```
ArrayList<String> meuArray = new ArrayList<>();
meuArray.add("");

//Popular array
```

---

```
mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (position == 0)
            //Não selecionou
        else
            //Selecionou
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Espero que ajude.